# How many documents are referenced by an index?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a collection of documents in a MongoDB database for which I've created a simple index using a command like:

```
db.fubar.createIndex({category: 1},{background: true});
```

After the indexing is complete, my queries for `fubar` documents with a specific value for `category` are completed much quicker than before, as expected.  So, all seems well.

However, I'd like to know how many documents in `fubar` are referenced by this new index.  Not every document in the collection has a `category` property, so I'd guess those documents aren't included in the index.

How can I find out exactly how many documents the collection's index references?

I also thought knowing how many documents an index references may indicate the progress of index creation on a collection.  That is, if I know a collection contains ***n*** documents and the index being created for the collection references ***m*** of them, then the index creation is ***m/n*** complete.  This would be helpful for large collections, like those in which ***n*** is many millions or billions.

Comment: Technically speaking the index references "all" of the documents unless you specifically ask it not to with the ["sparse"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/) option, and that actually is a common pitfall with "unique" indexes where people do not understand that. If you are actually wanting to know *"how many keys in the collection"* then [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) is the test for that as has been answered. So there would only be that `n` result from `$exists` in the index when "sparse" is used. Otherwise it's actually **all**.

Comment: I need to add specificity to my question.  If I could learn how many documents the index references and compare that with the number of documents in the collection, I can get an idea of the progress of index creation.

Comment: How was I not "specific"? **ALL** Documents are in the index, unless you "specifically" tell it not to with the "sparse" option. MongoDB is "schemaless" and therefore has no foreknowledge if a document actually contain the field you are specifying the index on. Understand now?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:**

You can write a query that returns all documents using `.hint()` to specify the index and perform `.count()` on it.

This should return the exact amount of documents the index runs over.

`db.fubar.find().hint({category: 1}).count()`

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/hint/

**Old answer:**

You can write a query that returns all documents where that key exists and perform `.count()` on it.

Ref: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/#index-use

> When performing a count, MongoDB can return the count using only the
>   index if:
>
> the query can use an index, the query only contains conditions on the
>   keys of the index, and the query predicates access a single contiguous
>   range of index keys.

You should be able to run something along these lines:

`db.fubar.find({category: { $exists: true }}).count()`

Comment: Wouldn't using `$exists` violate the "access a single contiguous range of index keys" condition?

Comment: You're right, it would have still gone against the entire document only literally counting the documents that had that key exist. Updated answer.